# Dell Precision 7510 Loses sound after upgrade from 14.04 (OEM) to 16.04

Tags: drivers, sound

So I just got my Dell Precision 7510 yesterday, and proceeded to upgrade it from 14.04 to 16.04 as I'd rather be on the latest release. Everything went fine except for the fact that my system does not detect a sound card anymore. If I go to System Settings > Sound, there is simply an empty box where my outputs should be detected. lspci reveals at least 2 devices that should show up:

```
Audio device: NVIDIA Corporation Device 0fbc (rev a1)
Audio device: Intel Corporation Sunrise Point-H HD Audio (rev 31)
```

I believe the Intel device is likely the one I need to get working again.

Under additional drivers, I noticed something is missing from before as well, though only open source drivers were in use on the system (except for the gpu).

I'd really rather not go back to 14.04 if possible, and I'd definitely not want to stay on that release (I'd rather this machine last me more than the 3 years left of support). It's been a while since I've used Ubuntu so I'd really appreciate the help of where to go from here.
At the moment I'm running sound through my H4n via USB, but I'd rather not have to do that long term.

EDIT: May be affected by this bug as my machine is using the same chipset: https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/pulseaudio/+bug/1616079

Answer (score 0, accepted):

*( first do  a real shutdown (not reboot) if not already done)*
It seems Intel soundcard is now the 2nd one.
 To select it,   install and launch pavucontrol (Pulseaudio volume),
go to "output devices"  tab,
click **green button** **"set as fallback"** near the Intel soundcard
(in your case, should be in the bottom)
[image]

As this fails, in case the problem was solved recently, you can try latest ALSA driver from Ubuntu ( daily build snapshots, see [here](https://launchpad.net/~ubuntu-audio-dev/+archive/ubuntu/alsa-daily))  :
Paste and run successively this 3 commands in terminal:
`sudo add-apt-repository ppa:ubuntu-audio-dev/alsa-daily 
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install  dkms oem-audio-hda-daily-dkms`
then reboot

As this failed too, may be Alsa is ok but not Pulseaudio:
check with alsamixer:
 Run  alsamixer in a maximized terminal,  use <kbd>F6</kbd> to select Intel soundcard : do you see your more  faders than "line out"? Anyway,  tweak all  volumes using left/right arrows to scroll thru faders, then  up/down to set each fader levels (set all to max for test) , m key to mute/unmute (unmute all)

EDIT: **Reset pulseaudio configuration:**  As Jackd sound server has sound working, and jackd use underlaying  Alsa layer, Alsa is also ok so probably the problem comes from Pulseaudio (which is another sound server using underlaying  Alsa like Jackd do) . Resetting the Pulseaudio config for current user can be done running this in a terminal:

`mv ~/.config/pulse ~/.config/pulseold`
then
`killall pulseaudio`
Pulseaudio will restart creating a new config.
Check also if you have tweak Pulseaudio config in /etc/pulse

EDIT2 : **Restore Alsa volume at startup** :
do  `sudo alsactl store`   and   `sudo alsactl store  1` when volumes are ok . 
The 2nd command may return error if you have no second  soundcard .
The `alsactl restore` and `alsactl restore 1` is done at startup.

Comment: I appreciate the help.
I can see all my ins and outs in pavucontrol, but adjusting the priority hasn't helped.  the sound pane in system settings still detects nothing, and I cant get any sound out of the system at this point.

Comment: In output device,  switch the Intel soundcard  "port" selection (try headphone and speaker), as the automatic selection fails sometimes

Comment: It would seem that no options come up under that menu. It is titled "Line Out (unplugged)" and there are no options. worth noting is that there is a headphone out, no line out. on the device. Plugging in headphones also does nothing. Something is wrong beyond this I think.

Comment: SO the chipset I have is detected by AlsaMixer as Realtek ALC3235, and I think it may be affected by this: https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/pulseaudio/+bug/1616079

Unsure about how to fix this as there is no solution offered.

Comment: See the answer , i added latest alsa driver install

Comment: thanks for the input, though I had already tried that earlier with no effect :(

Comment: added alsamixer test in case you didnt tried before ...

Comment: hey, thanks. I've been messing around with alsamixer for a while now. It has a few outputs listed. I can mess with the faders, mute and unmute, but none of this really changes anything. I've also tried "alsactl restore" with no luck.
What is interesting is that I installed Qjackctl, and lmms to see if they work. for some reason I can get audio output no problem from jack with lmms.

Comment: Added pulseaudio reset , this could solve

Comment: I think this has fixed it! I Really appreciate all your help! While the sound settings in the ubuntu config program still list no outputs, I can now get sound playback from other applications. switching between headphones and speakers is working correctly too!

Only thing left is that every time I boot, the speaker and headphone outs are set to muted in Alsamixer. in /etc/pluse there is only client.conf and daemon.conf I read somewhere that it might be pluse doing this.

Comment: cool, added restore alsa volume at startup (note this is usually  done automatically  at pulseaudio level, )